# Which Queue to use? Kafka, RabbitMQ, Redis, SQS, ActiveMQ or you name it

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, message-queue

This is my problem:
I need to have a queue to which I am going push with unlimited number of messages. Each message will have customer ID attached.

Each message then get consumed, message data will be transformed and sent to a API server.

However, the API server only allows receive a fixed number of messages per customer per second.

My question is: Which queue will be suitable for this requirement?

Comment: Calling the API server is not done by the messaging middleware but by the consumer. He is responsible to adher to the API server limits. Use any messaging middleware you like.

Comment: well, how do you limit the number of calls per customer effectively from consumer?

Comment: The cosumer will have to do some bookkeeping of API calls he made per customer per second. If the rate is exceeded he could pause consuming messages.

Answer (score 3):

**All of these** and then, none.

The service that reads from your queue and talks to the API should be the one responsible for keeping track of the API call rate and slow down (by waiting) when the rate is exceeded.

This is especially suited if these rate limits are complex (per customer, etc.) plus you keep your message broker as an implementation detail.